# Span Bootstrap well to cover entire page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap well in my html code as follows:

```
<div class="well well-lg">
    <!-- Div code -->
</div>
```

The elements of the div do not span the entire page, but I want the well to span the entire page. I added the following code in my css file:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

.well {
height:100%;
}
```

This code isn't helping to span the well on the entire page.

What code do I add in my css to achieve what I want?

Comment: Is that <div> directly under <body> tag?

Comment: @Pangloss Yes, it's directly under the <body> tag.

Comment: It seems to be working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n83gpwq2/).

Comment: Are you asking for removing the white space beneath?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it a number of ways, you could use the following:

```
.well {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But this might not work well with your current project as I don't know what else is on your web page.

You could also use

```
.well {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

But this wouldn't be supported as well with some older browsers.  See it's support here http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Answer (score 0):

**Tejasi Latkar**,  Hi there.  The suggestion by **Conormcafee** is what will help you here.

But if you only want the `well` to take up/fill the rest of the screen then you could try this...

```
.well {
  height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 50px);
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 50px);
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

What this does is it will subtract the height of 50px from the total viewport height.
Let's say your navbar has a height of 50px.
Using this code the `well` will now only reach to the bottom of the screen.
And not 50px past the bottom of the screen.

I hope this gives you another option if this is what you are looking for.